# How to construct a dictionary from two dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
x = {"x1":1,"x2":2,"x3":3}
```

and I have another dictionary:

```
y = {"y1":1,"y2":2,"y3":3}
```

Is there any neat way to constract a 3rd dictionary from the previous two:

```
z = {"y1":1,"x2":2,"x1":1,"y2":2}
```

Comment: What happened to `x3` and `y3`?

Comment: Sorry, I might didn't explain very well. I don't want to add the whole two dictionaries to make new one. I just want some keys from the first one and some other keys from the second one then create a new dictionary

Comment: @user2468276 I've updated my answer with what you wanted.

Comment: ```x = { **x, **y }```

Answer (score 9):

**If you want the whole 2 dicts:**

```
x = {"x1":1,"x2":2,"x3":3}
y = {"y1":1,"y2":2,"y3":3}


z = dict(x.items() + y.items())
print z
```

**Output:**

```
{'y2': 2, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 3, 'y3': 3, 'x1': 1}
```

**If you want the partial dict:**

```
x = {"x1":1,"x2":2,"x3":3}
y = {"y1":1,"y2":2,"y3":3}

keysList = ["x2", "x1", "y1", "y2"]
z = {}

for key, value in dict(x.items() + y.items()).iteritems():
    if key in keysList:
        z.update({key: value})

print z
```

**Output**

```
{'y1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x1': 1, 'y2': 2}
```

Comment: First solution will work in python2, but not in python3

Comment: @JpuntoMarcos You are right (an old answer), You can use `z = dict(list(x.items()) + list(y.items()))` for python3 but keep in mind it's more expensive.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `copy` for `x` then `update` to add the keys and values from `y`:

```
z = x.copy()
z.update(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
dict([(key, d[key]) for d in [x,y] for key in d.keys() if key not in ['x3', 'y3']])
{'x2': 2, 'y1': 1, 'x1': 1, 'y2': 2}
```